# Is Nyquist plot an alternative way insted of root locus plot?

Tags: control-theory

With Nyquist plot, you can check stability. With root locus plot, you can do exactly the same. Check the stability.

My question is if there are any differences between root locus plot and Nyquist plot?

With root locus plot, it's very improtant to use transfer functions of z p k values. That's all I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both methods asses stability but with different means.

The rootlocus plot is most often used when you are dealing with one design-parameter (most time simple P-controller with gain $K$). It will show how the roots change when changing the design-parameter. Hence, it is a dircect way to asses stability (negative real part) and also to see for which parameter range the system oscillates (has overshoot). The root locus plot cannot be used for systems with dead time.

The Nyquist plot is an indirect way to asses stability. We see from the Nyquist plot if the given open loop system is closed loop stable. It also gives informations about the stability margins like phase margin and gain margin. It can be used for systems with dead time.

Comment: Damn! That's a good answer. Do you know how to do root locus analysis numericaly ?

Comment: What do you mean with numericaly? In matlab and in Octave you should just need to define the transfer function. Using rlocus(TF_object) should give you the root locus plot.

Comment: Another advantage of Nyquist would be that you do not need a model. You can also check for stability and margin using just data from an experimental FRF measurement. And it is probably less computational expensive as rootlocus.

Comment: So I assume root locus is an obsolete method for stability if Nyquist plot is much better ?

Comment: When I mean numericaly, I mean using algoritms to compute root locus.

Comment: Yes, in my years in as an engineer, I have never used the root-locus method.